# Multiple Query Writing in Single Query

Tags: sql

I have two tables in Database , I need to select a field from one table and update it in another table with a condition where id is same .. Is it Possible to write in single query ???

Comment: Could you give us more details on the tables and fields you are talking about? Could you give us an example?

Comment: first table name is register ... second table table name is storage . now i want to update all values of field email from register to storage ...

Answer (score 8):

This should work for you:

```
update storage 
    set storage.email = (select register.email
                           from register 
                           where register.id = storage.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it is, you could do this for example:

```
UPDATE Origin SET DesiredColumn = NewValue
FROM Origin
JOIN NewTable ON Origin.Id = NewTable.Id
```

And guess the column names were like `DesiredColumn` in the updating table and `NewValue` in the table that holds the `new value`.

Comment: Is there a benefit to using this over using a sub-query? And is it platform independent?

Comment: I guess it is platform independent as i found it here
http://www.paragoncorporation.com/ArticleDetail.aspx?ArticleID=27
and regarding performance i guess it doesnt have any impact on latest database systems.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is possible, although the syntax depends on the type of SQL you are using.

Here is an example for T-SQL (for Microsoft SQL Server)

```
UPDATE
   S
SET
   Email = R.Email
FROM
   dbo.Register R
INNER JOIN dbo.Storage S
   ON S.RegisterID = R.RegisterID
```

Comment: While the syntax you've posted depends on the SQL product, the same is not true of all SQL syntax. That's why we have SQL Standards. I can rewrite you syntax as Standard SQL-92 using scalar subqueries (which is supported by most SQL products) and as Standard SQL-99 using `MERGE` (which is supported by many SQL products, including SQL Server, Oracle and PostgreSQL).